# Como remover o background de uma imagem usando o watershed no android?

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, processamento-de-imagens

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que classifica imagens de feridas. Para isso,eu preciso destacar a regiao de interesse do background para facilitar o trabalho do algoritmo de classificação.

O usuário utiliza o touch do celular para informar ao algoritmo watershed onde ele irá segmentar a área da ferida. Com isso, eu passo as coordenadas e a imagem a ser segmentada.

Porém, estou com dificuldade de utilizar o watershed juntamente com a região demarcada pelo usuário por não ter experiencia com opencv+android.

No código abaixo eu passo a imagem a o conjunto de coordenadas para a função de extração do backgroud, só que ainda não consegui completar por não saber em que ponto eu passo as coordenadas dá área para o watershed segmentar somente aquela região.

Tela principal

[image]

Método de extração do background

```
typealias Coordinates = Pair<Point, Point>
private fun extractForegroundFromBackground(coordinates: Coordinates, currentPhotoPath: String): String {
    // TODO: Provide complex object that has both path and extension


    val width: Int  = bitmap.getWidth()
    val height: Int = bitmap.getHeight()
    val rect = Rect(coordinates.first, coordinates.second)//Coordinates ROI
    val rgba = Mat()
    val edges = Mat()
    val hierarchy = Mat()
    val gray_mat = Mat()
    val threeChannel = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, gray_mat)
    //Conversion colors
    cvtColor(gray_mat, rgba, COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
    cvtColor(rgba, threeChannel, COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    threshold(threeChannel, threeChannel, 100.0, 255.0, THRESH_OTSU)
    //Find contours
    Canny(threeChannel, edges, 10.0, 100.0)
    val contours: List<MatOfPoint> = ArrayList()
    findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    val markers = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_32S, Scalar(0.0))
    //Draw contours
    for (i in contours.indices) {
        drawContours(markers, contours, i, Scalar(i + 1.0), -1, 8, hierarchy, INTER_MAX, Point())
    }
    val marker_tempo = Mat()
    markers.convertTo(marker_tempo, CvType.CV_32S)
    //Start the WaterShed Segmentation
    watershed(rgba, markers)
    //Generated output
    marker_tempo.convertTo(markers, CvType.CV_8U)
    result_Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    Utils.matToBitmap(edges, result_Bitmap)
    image.setImageBitmap(result_Bitmap)

    return currentPhotoPath
}
```

Saida:

[image]

Eu preciso retornar a imagem com o fundo preto e somente a região da ferida em destaque, conforme imagem exemplo abaixo.

[image]

Comment: Eu não manjo muito de processamento de imagens, mas muitos algorítmos funcionam assim: Há uma cor de referência do fundo, um algorítmo do tipo flood fill, seleciona os pixels adjacentes que estejam dentre uma tolerância/limiar/threshold.Existe um parâmetro que representa a diferença de cor (delta E https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) ou você pode usar a diferença euclidiana (A raiz do produto escalar da diferença das cores com ela mesma). Eu já fiz uma solução desse tipo, mas talvez você esteja utilizando aprendizado de máquina para identificar as feridas, isso eu não sei te ajudar

Comment: Isso funciona bem quando o fundo tem uma cor distinta como o chroma key em videos. E o flood fill pode começar pelos cantos, pela borda, ou por uma cor definida pelo usuário.

Comment: Pior que pro meu caso o ambiente nao é controlável.

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://imgur.com/KOm6tJg. É um prototipo bem ruim que fiz em 10 min. Mas a idéia é essa.

Comment: Bacana, porem para as imagens que uso acho que precisaria ter interferencias manuais de regioes onde precisaria delimitar ate onde segmentar para acabar nao 'comendo' a ferida

Comment: Esse é só um prototipo mesmo, de fato, é necessário `clusterizar` os pixels e delimitar regiões, usar `k-médias`, excluir clusters de poucos pixels, e por aí vai. Realmente, eu não trabalho com Java ou Android.

Comment: Sakei, @Edney. Veja essa outra pergunta onde evolui um pouco o codigo... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60978380/how-to-remove-the-background-of-the-image-of-interest-using-opencv-on-android

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107478/discussion-between-carlos-diego-and-edney).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private fun extractForegroundFromBackground(coordinates: Coordinates, currentPhotoPath: String): String {
    // TODO: Provide complex object that has both path and extension

    // Matrices that OpenCV will be using internally
    val bgModel = Mat()
    val fgModel = Mat()

    val srcImage = Imgcodecs.imread(currentPhotoPath)
    val iterations = 5

    // Mask image where we specify which areas are background, foreground or probable background/foreground
    val firstMask = Mat()

    val source = Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD.toDouble()))
    val rect = Rect(coordinates.first, coordinates.second)

    // Run the grab cut algorithm with a rectangle (for subsequent iterations with touch-up strokes,
    // flag should be Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
    Imgproc.grabCut(srcImage, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, iterations, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

    // Create a matrix of 0s and 1s, indicating whether individual pixels are equal
    // or different between "firstMask" and "source" objects
    // Result is stored back to "firstMask"
    Core.compare(firstMask, source, firstMask, Core.CMP_EQ)

    // Create a matrix to represent the foreground, filled with white color
    val foreground = Mat(srcImage.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0))

    // Copy the foreground matrix to the first mask
    srcImage.copyTo(foreground, firstMask)

    // Create a red color
    val color = Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0)
    // Draw a rectangle using the coordinates of the bounding box that surrounds the foreground
    Imgproc.rectangle(srcImage, coordinates.first, coordinates.second, color)

    // Create a new matrix to represent the background, filled with white color
    val background = Mat(srcImage.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

    val mask = Mat(foreground.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0))
    // Convert the foreground's color space from BGR to gray scale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground, mask, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    // Separate out regions of the mask by comparing the pixel intensity with respect to a threshold value
    Imgproc.threshold(mask, mask, 254.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    // Create a matrix to hold the final image
    val dst = Mat()
    // copy the background matrix onto the matrix that represents the final result
    background.copyTo(dst)

    val vals = Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(0.0))
    // Replace all 0 values in the background matrix given the foreground mask
    background.setTo(vals, mask)

    // Add the sum of the background and foreground matrices by applying the mask
    Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask)

    // Save the final image to storage
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(currentPhotoPath + "_tmp.png", dst)

    // Clean up used resources
    firstMask.release()
    source.release()
    bgModel.release()
    fgModel.release()
    vals.release()
    dst.release()

    return currentPhotoPath
}
```